# Get Html elements inside div By ID (ID is not Unique)

Tags: c#, html

I am developing add to read web browser data and store it into a dictionary.
During this process, I need to access data By ID but the IDs are not Unique on the page. The page looks like this.

```
<div id="ID1"> 
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="1000" data-field="1">
            text
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<div id="ID2"> 
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="1000" data-field="2">
            Some other text
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

both div elements are on the same page

when I get element By Id It only gives me the first element, not the second one.

Here is My code

```
            HtmlElement myElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ID2");
            HtmlElement myElements2 = myElements.Document.GetElementById("1000");

            if (myElements2.InnerText != null)
            {
                //Do something
            }
```

How Can I get the inner text of the second element by ID

Comment: It's not valid HTML to have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: @vlumi I know this is not valid but The Url I am trying to fetch data from has so many elements with the same ID but they are divided via DIV

Comment: @JayeshGoyani can you explain how to impliment document.querrySelectorAll() with windowsform and C#. I am reading element from Webbrowser.document and document doesnt have querrySelectorAll()

Comment: Use jquery, $("#ID2").find("td[id='1000']")

Comment: Sorry my mistake I thought it is web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best and the easiest answer I came up with 
I figured out the data-field is a unique value in the page so I looped through the elements and compared it with data-field

```
HtmlElement Buildingcontacts = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ID2");
HtmlElementCollection ifiels = Buildingcontacts.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td");
            foreach (HtmlElement element in ifiels)
            {
                string datafieldx = element.GetAttribute("data-field");
                if (datafieldx == "2")
                {
                    if (element.InnerText != null)
                    {
                       //do Somthing
                    }
                }

            }
```